# .htaccess how redirect url param to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url, parameters, query-string

How do I redirect this URL string:
http://mydomain.com/sub?param1

To this:
http://mydomain.com/sub/param1/

Note, there is no value set for param1, just "param1" for the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture the query string, you need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^sub$ /sub/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

However if there is no `http://mydomain.com/sub/param1/` or any rule to catch that it would still fail.

The above condition is set to redirect only if `http://mydomain.com/sub` contains a non empty query string attached.

Comment: This worked, but now how do I prevent the query string from being appended back onto the new URL?

Comment: @PatrickWyzorski [kindly mark my answer as the right answer if it worked for you, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about) As for the removing the query string I have updated the answer so you can use the new code. Keep in mind in some cases you may get cached from the 301 redirect so you may not instantly see the removal of the query string, in this case, try using a different browser just to confirm it worked.